# Bundler and gems on github

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

So when you have bundler install a gem from github, it doesn't *actually* get installed, does it?  `gem list` won't list those gems.

Which brings me to my conundrum: I'm working on a script that wants to use one of these gems that don't actually get installed. Now what? I could check out the github repo manually and build/install the gem, but now I've got one version being managed by bundler and another that's not. I could point the script to the gem directory in ~/.rvm but that's not a great idea when it comes time to go to production.

I'm trying to find a bundler command that will make any gems from github "register" with rubygems, but nothing so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried typing "bundle show agemthatdoesntshowingemlist" (replace agemthatdoesntshowingemlist by a gem that doesn't show in gem list)

Comment: Sure, that lists the location of where it is in `~/.rvm/gems` but it apparently isn't "registered" with rubygems because `require 'hiddengem'` doesn't work: `LoadError: no such file to load — hiddengem`. Like I say, I could require the full path to the gem, and my script would work just fine on my local system, but if I put the code anywhere else it's gonna break all over the place.

Answer (score 2):

Ironically this is the same answer as a previous question I had, which I answered myself with this same solution (although it was a little different in bundler 0.9):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'
require 'hiddengem'
```

`bundler/setup` makes the bundler "stack" available just as if they were regularly installed gems. Sooner or later I'll remember this. :)

Answer (score 0):

[rubygems-bundler](https://github.com/mpapis/rubygems-bundler) is a gem that addresses this issue.  If it is installed on your system, you shouldn't need any extra code in your project.  It may need to be installed as @global, so, to sum it all up:

```
$ rvm use @global
$ gem install rubygems-bundler
```

And then, to get back to the rvm version you were using:

```
$ rvm use @
```